# How to Create Parameter References in a PHP Function

Tags: php, function, reference

I want to increase $x by 1:

```
$x = 1;

function addOne($x) {
  $x++;
  return $x;
}

$x = addOne($x);
```

Is there a way to do this with references, so I don't need to `return $x`, I can just write `addOne($x)`?

Comment: I think you want to build something more complex out of this right? Otherwise you could just do `$x++;` :D

Comment: It does sort of depend on what is being passed as an argument to the function since [objects are (kind of) always passed by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you're looking for, a by-ref parameter indicated by `&`.

```
$x = 1;

function addOne(&$x) {
  $x++;
}

addOne($x);
```

Some notes:

- By-ref parameters require that the value passed in not be a literal.  Given my example above, `addOne(5)` would throw a fatal exception
- References are not needed for objects (including stdClass objects), as all objects are passed by reference as of PHP 5.
- References ARE needed for arrays, as arrays in PHP are not treated as objects
- If you want a return value of a function passed by reference, you would indicate the reference on the function name (e.g. `function &foo()`).

More info on references: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: Was gonna mention giving some info on references in your answer but you beat me to it.

Comment: Is there a difference between using the reference in the function declaration, versus in the function call? 

Like `function addOne($x)` but then just call it with `addOne(&$x)`?

Comment: @DonnyP This is not C. Calling it that way will issue a warning.

Comment: @FloydThreepwood depends on the version of PHP. In newer versions than PHP 5.3, calltime-pass-by-ref will cause a fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = 1;

function addOne(&$x) {
    $x++;
}

addOne($x);
```

The `&` sign shows that it takes the parameter by reference. So it increments `$x` in the function and it will also affect the `$x` variable in the calling scope.

See also: http://php.net/references for a quick overview about them.